# Float element's father element is not at the right position

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using the `rem` to create a mobile web project.Now I am facing a problem.

My code is below:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
        body {
                background-color: green;
            }

        #top {
            /*height: .9rem;*/
        }

        #top::after,
        #top::before {
            /*content: '';
            display: block;
            clear: both;
            visibility: hidden;*/
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        #data-item {
            margin-top: 4rem;
        }

        #data-item .image-list {
            width: 4.5rem;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        #data-item .image-list .image-list .div-image {
            width: 1.4rem;
            height: 1.4rem;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: #6641E2;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/mui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        mui.init()
    </script>
    <section id="top">
        <div id="addImage" style="height: .90rem; width: 1.60rem; float:right ; padding-top: .20rem; position: relative;background-color: red; z-index: 999;">
            <span style="display: inline-block; margin-right: .20rem;">ADD</span>
       </div>
    </section>
    <section id="data-item">
        <ul class="mui-table-view">
            <li class="mui-table-view-cell">
                <div class="title"><img src="images/vip.png" alt="" /><span class="date">6月１日</span></div>
                <p class="item-description"></p>
                <ul class="image-list">
                    <li>
                        <div class="div-image"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="div-image"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="div-image"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="div-image"></div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="mui-table-view-cell">Item 2</li>
            <li class="mui-table-view-cell">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</body>
```

I look the result in the chrome console, I choose the mobile device **iPhone5**.
The screen is like this:

[image]

I check the element in the `Elements` tab.
I see that the `#top` `section` is 320*0.
 My question is why the `#addImage` `div` has the `margin-top` too. I set the `margin-top` for the `#data-item` `section`?

Why does not the red `div` at the top-right corner?

Comment: At fisrt view, you didn't close the "addImage" div. Sometimes the use of a validator can help you to solve this issues. [link](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: @Triby Yes, I have a slip.

Comment: Regardless if the issue is solved, why the span inside the "addImage" div? You could just set padding to "position" the text.

Comment: @Triby As you said, I should delete the "addImage" div, and set the padding-left to the "#top section"?

Comment: No, I meant you should delete the span and left just the "ADD" text inside the "addImage" div; then, adjust the alignment and padding of "addImage" to set the text inside. This will not position the element where you want, but it helps you to get a cleaner code.

Comment: @Triby  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

add this style to the parent:

`#top{
    overflow: auto;
}`